# How to factor out main method of Scala objects into a shared location?

Tags: scala, refactoring, program-entry-point

In several Scala objects I have defined a main method that invokes runTests which is an abstract method in Test. Is there a way for the main method to be factored out into a common location (Trait or other solution) so that I can still run the test in Eclipse by keying <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>?

This is what I have at present,

https://github.com/janekdb/stair-chess/blob/master/src/chess/model/BoardModelTest.scala

```
object BoardModelTest extends Test with TestUtils {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    runTests
  }

  def runTests {
  ...
```

https://github.com/janekdb/stair-chess/blob/master/src/test/Test.scala

```
trait Test {

  def runTests: Unit
  ...
```

Comment: is there a reason you are not using ScalaTest or specs2 and rolling out your own test framework?

Comment: @tolitius My current focus is learning Scala fundamentals so the more I do for myself the better I will meet my goal. Later I will look to library and framework adoption. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have Eclipse on this computer so I can't test if it works with Ctrl+F11, but I think you want a self-type:

```
trait Main {
  self: Test => 
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    runTests
  }
}
```

You then just mix it in after your `Test` trait:

```
object BoardModelTest extends Test with TestUtils with Main {
  def runTests {}
}
```

Comment: Final outcome: Added Main.scala and reduced line count elsewhere by 5 x 5 lines: https://github.com/janekdb/stair-chess/commit/11bdffffa861132d3a7f3e58e989241cd33460c5